# How to cast a generic array into another type?

Tags: c#, arrays, generics

I'm still trying to find a fast way of how to convert a generic array of type TOutput to another array of type TInput. All my arrays are always of a numeric datatype, but since C# has no type constraint to Numeric as often requested, I currently have to live with this constraint. The suggested methods, like casting to an object before, seems to slow down my cast tremendously. Currently I have a large if/else construct that check for a type and cast to a defined type using pointer arithmetic, but this is way to large to handle for the future. Parallel.For seems a good way to get rid of pointers and to speed up thing, but still the C# generic constraints seem to be a problem, but still the Tout in the code below is a problem. Here's my code:

```
    public static OutputType[] Cast<InputType, OutputType>(InputType[] inputArray_in)
    {
        var aRange = Partitioner.Create(0, inputArray_in.Length);
        OutputType[] aResult = new OutputType[inputArray_in.Length];

        Parallel.ForEach(aRange, (r) =>
        {
            for (int i = r.Item1; i < r.Item2; i++)
            {
                aResult[i] = (OutputType)(inputArray_in[i]);
            }
        });

        return aResult;
    }
```

Example:

```
float[] A = { 0.1f, 0.2f, 0.6f };
int []B = Cast<float, int>(A);
```

In all cases my array types are numerical values (float, short, double,...) and most of the time, the arrays are about 512x512 images, but in a stack of about 1000 slices in a volume.
Do you see any chance to have a simple way of performing this?

Test Code

```
public static class CastTest
{
    delegate double[] CastMethod(int[] input);

    public static unsafe double[] Cast1(int[] input)
    {
        int N = input.Length;
        double[] output = new double[N];

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) output[i] = (double)(input[i]);

        return output;
    }

    public static unsafe double[] Cast2(int[] input)
    {
        int N = input.Length;
        double[] output = new double[N];

        fixed (double* output_pinned = output)
        {
            double* outp = output_pinned;

            fixed (int* input_pinned = input)
            {
                int* inp = input_pinned;

                for (int i = 0; i < N; i++, inp++, outp++) *outp = (double)(*inp);
            }

            return output;
        }
    }

    public static unsafe double[] Cast3(int[] input)
    {
        int N = input.Length;
        double[] output = new double[N];

        fixed (double* output_pinned = output)
        {
            double* outp = output_pinned;

            fixed (int* input_pinned = input)
            {
                int* inp = input_pinned;

                for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) outp[i] = (double)(inp[i]);
            }

            return output;
        }
    }

    public static unsafe double[] Cast4(int[] input)
    {
        int N = input.Length;
        double[] output = new double[N];

        fixed (double* output_pinned = output)
        {
            fixed (int* input_pinned = input)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) output_pinned[i] = (double)(input_pinned[i]);
            }
        }

        return output;
    }

    public static unsafe double[] Cast5(int[] input)
    {
        return Array.ConvertAll<int, double>(input, x => (double)x);
    }

    public static double[] Cast6(int[] input)
    {
        var aRange = Partitioner.Create(0, input.Length);

        int N = input.Length;
        double[] output = new double[N];

        Parallel.ForEach(aRange, (r) =>
            {
                for (int i = r.Item1; i < r.Item2; i++) output[i] = (double)(input[i]);
            });

        return output;
    }

    public unsafe static double[] Cast7(int[] input)
    {
        var aRange = Partitioner.Create(0, input.Length);

        int N = input.Length;
        double[] output = new double[N];

        Parallel.ForEach(aRange, (r) =>
        {
            fixed (double* output_pinned = output)
            {
                double* outp = output_pinned + r.Item1;

                fixed (int* input_pinned = input)
                {
                    int* inp = input_pinned + r.Item1;

                    for (int i = r.Item1; i < r.Item2; i++, outp++, inp++) *outp = (double)(*inp);
                }
            }
        });

        return output;
    }

    public unsafe static double[] Cast8(int[] input)
    {
        var result = (from m in input.AsParallel() select (double)m).ToArray();

        return result;
    }


    public static double[] Cast9(int[] input)
    {
        return  (from m in input select (double)m).ToArray(); 
    }

    public static double[] Cast10(int[] input)
    {
        return (from m in input.AsParallel() select (double)m).ToArray(); 
    }

    public static double[] Cast11(int[] input)
    {
        return new List<double>(input.Select(p => (double)p)).ToArray(); 
    }

    static int[] A = new int[100000];
    const int runs = 10000;

    public static void StartTest()
    {
        TestMethod("1", Cast1);
        TestMethod("2", Cast2);
        TestMethod("3", Cast3);
        TestMethod("4", Cast4);
        TestMethod("5", Cast5);
        TestMethod("6", Cast6);
        TestMethod("7", Cast7);
        TestMethod("8", Cast8);
        TestMethod("9", Cast9);
        TestMethod("10", Cast10);
        TestMethod("11", Cast11);
    }

    static void TestMethod(string Name, CastMethod method)
    {
        var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++) { double[] res = method(A); }

        timer.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: {1}ms", Name, timer.ElapsedMilliseconds));
    }
}
```

Thank you
Martin

Comment: Can you give a specific example here of what `InputType`, `OutputType` and `Tout` might be ?

Comment: Hi Marc, I'm sorry I made a mistake in the code. I did an update.

Comment: does doing it in linq make a difference? (i'm not near dev environment but this is roughly the gist of it) var result = (from m in range.AsParallel() select (int)m).ToArray();

Comment: also lookup C# covariant/contravariant generics there might be a clue for you there. the language doesn't support it as far as I know but it's an interesting read. http://buiba.blogspot.com.au/2009/06/so-i-get-onto-phone-for-my-first-job.html

Comment: @Peter. I tried your solution. Its slower than all currently tested alternatives. I will post a test code here soon.

Comment: you won't benefit from AsParallel over a small set. it set's up a bit of infrastructure to manage threading. did you try it over a large set of data?

Comment: Hi Peter, yes I did 10000 Iterations over 1000000 elements. In that case the Parallel.For with pointers is the fastest. Otherwise if the data gets smaller the regular pointer loop is the fastest.

Answer (score 8):

There is no magic conversion (when using generics etc) between numeric types like this; there are tricks like `Convert.ChangeType`, or `dynamic`, but both involve an intermediate box/unbox.

Personally, I'd just be using:

```
float[] A = { 0.1f, 0.2f, 0.6f };
int[] B = Array.ConvertAll(A, x => (int)x);
```

This offloads the conversion logic to the compiler (to use the correct conversion from `float` to `int` without intermediaries or reflection). It is, however, not usable inside generics - i.e. `x => (OutputType)x` will not work.

Comment: Hi Marc, compared to all the other methods its about a factor 1.5 to 2 slower than all other methods. I will post a test code here to verify for you all.

Comment: @msedi are you saying that `Array.ConvertAll` is slower than `Convert.ChangeType` ? Also: what size is your array?

Comment: No, of course not ;-) I posted a test code. Where you can see the results. Interestingly there a differences running it in VS or without VS. Differences in x86 and x64, and also in Release in Debug mode of course.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this?

```
public static TOut[] Cast<TOut,TIn>(TIn[] arr) {
        return arr.Select(x => (TOut)Convert.ChangeType(x,typeof(TOut))).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did. But for my purpose it's to slow. Comparing your method to my pointer methods is round about a factor of 10 in performance.

Comment: I don't think there is a faster way without using unsafe code. If you need performance then your approach with pointers is the best

Comment: @user1077243. You are surely right. This is what I currently do, but this causes me a lot of headache since C# does not allow pointer to generics and I have to do alot for my own.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use simply `Cast` for lists, it's LINQ Cast method member of `System.Linq.Enumerable` :

```
float[] A = { 0.1f, 0.2f, 0.6f };
int[] B = A.Cast(Of int).ToArray();
```

You can read about it here : [Enumerable.Cast(Of TResult) Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx)

Comment: That's right, but using the .Cast method gives me errors in cases where a cast is not possible, e.g. from float to int. If I want to simply cast it that way it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I did three trivial experiments over a float array with 38988 items in it (I just cut and pasted a bunch of arbitrary values over and over again)

```
//_a = array of floats


// pretty standard way of doing it 4ms
_result = (from m in _a select (int)m).ToArray();

// I was rather disappointed with this 35ms
_result = (from m in _a.AsParallel() select (int)m).ToArray();

// using a list rather surprised me 1ms
_result = new List<int>(_a.Select(p => (int)p)).ToArray();
```

so I don't know how these compare with your tests but I'd say selecting into the generic list is pretty effective.

**EDIT:**

I'm adding my code. I must be missing something because I get quite different results from my example as compared to running your example.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using (var x = new ArrayCast())
        {
            x.Run();
        } 

        using (var x = new ArrayCastList())
        {
            x.Run();
        }
        using (var x = new ArrayCastAsParallel())
        {
            x.Run();
        }

        while (Console.Read() != 'q')
        {
            ;    // do nothing...
        }
    }
}

public abstract class Experiment : IAmATest, IDisposable
{
    private Stopwatch _timer;


    protected bool IgnoreAssert { get; set; }

    #region IAmATest Members

    public abstract void Arrange();
    public abstract void Act();
    public abstract void Assert();

    #endregion

    public void Run()
    {
        _timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        Arrange();
        _timer.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(":", "Arrange", _timer.ElapsedMilliseconds));

        _timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++)
        Act();
        _timer.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(":", "Act", _timer.ElapsedMilliseconds));

        if (IgnoreAssert) { return; }

        _timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        Assert();
        _timer.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(":", "Assert", _timer.ElapsedMilliseconds));
    }

    public abstract void Dispose();
}

public class ArrayCast : Experiment
{
    private int[] _a;
    double[] _result;

    public override void Arrange()
    {
        IgnoreAssert = true;
        _a = new int[100000];
    }

    public override void Act()
    {
            _result = (from m in _a select (double)m).ToArray();
    }

    public override void Assert() { }

    public override void Dispose() { _a = null; }
}

public class ArrayCastAsParallel : Experiment
{
    private int[] _a;
    double[] _result;

    public override void Arrange()
    {
        IgnoreAssert = true;
        _a = new int[100000];
    }

    public override void Act()
    {
        _result = (from m in _a.AsParallel() select (double)m).ToArray();
    }

    public override void Assert() { }

    public override void Dispose() { _a = null; }
}

public class ArrayCastList : Experiment
{
    private int[] _a;
    double[] _result;

    public override void Arrange()
    {
        IgnoreAssert = true;
        _a = new int[100000];
    }

    public override void Act()
    {
        var x = new List<double>(_a.Select(p => (double)p));
    }

    public override void Assert() { }

    public override void Dispose() { _a = null; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your example. I have added it to my test code an made a run on all cases. It seems that all tests that have to do with Linq are extremly slow. Would you please have a run with the test code on your machine? Thanks Martin